# How to replace two things at once in a string?

Tags: python, string

Say I have a string, `"ab"`.

I want to replace `"a"` with `"b"` and `"b"` with `"a"` in one swoop.

So in the end, the string should be `"ba"` and not `"aa"` or `"bb"` and not use more than one line. Is this doable?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

When you need to swap variables, say *x* and *y*, a common pattern is to introduce a temporary variable *t* to help with the swap:  `t = x; x = y; y = t`.

The same pattern can also be used with strings:

```
>>> # swap a with b
>>> 'obama'.replace('a', '%temp%').replace('b', 'a').replace('%temp%', 'b')
'oabmb'
```

This technique isn't new.  It is described in PEP 378 as a way to convert between American and European style decimal separators and thousands separators (for example from `1,234,567.89` to `1.234.567,89`. Guido has endorsed this as a reasonable technique.

Comment: Is everyone okay with the fact that any string containing %temp% will be altered incorrectly?

Comment: I tend to do this with something ridiculous like like -\_(descriptor)\_-.  Wordy but chances of collision are *slim.

Comment: If you want _really_ obscure strings, use something with unicode characters from the Private Use Area as markers (or even undefined characters). The chance of encountering multiple of them at once by accident are really very slim indeed.

Answer (score 26):

```
import string
"abaababb".translate(string.maketrans("ab", "ba"))
# result: 'babbabaa'
```

Note that this only works for one-character substitutions.

For longer substrings or substitutions, this is a bit complex, but might work:

```
import re

def replace_all(repls, str):
    # return re.sub('|'.join(repls.keys()), lambda k: repls[k.group(0)], str)                                     
    return re.sub('|'.join(re.escape(key) for key in repls.keys()),
                  lambda k: repls[k.group(0)], str)                                     


text =  "i like apples, but pears scare me"
print replace_all({"apple": "pear", "pear": "apple"}, text)
```

Unfortunately <s>this won't work if you include any regexp special characters</s> you can't use regexps this way :(

(Thanks @TimPietzcker)

Comment: NVM, gotcha.  Is there a way to do it for more than one character? Say if I want to change a to "ad"?

Comment: You can replace any number of single characters with some other single characters. If you wanted to replace strings (for example, `"apple"` with `"yummy"` but `"pear"` with `"clown"`), this would not be appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

If you are OK with two lines, this is more elegant.

```
d={'a':'b','b':'a'}
''.join(d[s] for s in "abaababbd" if s in d.keys())
```

Comment: `''.join(d[s] if s in d else s for s in "abaababbd")`

Comment: @wim's answer is the best one on here.

Comment: `''.join(d.get(s,s) for s in "abaababbd")`

Answer (score 2):

Your example is a little bit abstract but in the past I've used [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/81330-single-pass-multiple-replace/) which builds a regular expression to do single-pass multiple replace. Here's my tweaked version of it:

```
import re 

def multiple_replace(dict, text): 
  regex = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, dict.keys())))
  return regex.sub(lambda mo: dict[mo.group(0)], text)
```

Note that the keys (searchstrings) are re.escaped.

In your case it would be:

```
from utils import multiple_replace

print multiple_replace({
    "a": "b",
    "b": "a"
}, "ab")
```

**UPDATE:**

By now this is basically the same as [Amadan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8687035/63736)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('.', lambda m: {'a':'b', 'b':'a'}.get(m.group(), m.group()), 'abc')
'bac'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
the_string="ab"
new_string=""

for x in range(len(the_string)):
    if the_string[x]=='a':
        new_string+='b'
        continue
    if the_string[x]=='b':
        new_string+='a'
        continue
    new_string+=the_string[x]

the_string=new_string

print the_string
```

Comment: OP: "and not use more than one line"

Comment: Well, I guess I cheated too, with the `import`... :P