# How can I format a float to separate by thousands, inverting dot and commas?

Tags: python, pandas, format, dataframe

How can I format a float, from a pandas dataframe, to separate thousands by dots and commas, instead by commas and dots? ?

Input:

```
112299420.40
```

Actual output:

```
112,299,420.40
```

Required output:

```
112.299.420,40
```

My code:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '{:,.2f}'.format(x) if abs(x) < 10000 else '{:,.0f}'.format(x))
```

How can I change this piece of code to produce the required output?

I've tried to change it the intuitive way, but without success...

**From:** `'{:,.2f}'`

**To:** `'{:.,2f}'`

Comment: You may find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8687380/5827958) helpful.

Comment: I'm reading PEP 0378 right now! Thanks!

Comment: 43 second response time.  That's a record.

Comment: Can you use s.replace('.','_').replace(',','.').replace('_',',')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 2.7 string formatting features don't seem to help in this case. However, you can use the `locale` module and set your locale to a country/language which uses the thousands/decimal separators you want (in the example below, Brazilian Portuguese):

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_br.utf-8')
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: locale.format('%.2f', x, grouping=True))
```

Example:

```
In [45]: pd.Series([1111.15, 123456.78])
Out[45]:
0     1.111,15
1   123.456,78
dtype: float64
```

---

If you want to ignore decimals for numbers under 10000 (as it looks like from your code):

```
In [49]: pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: locale.format('%.2f', x, grouping=True) if abs(x)>10000 else locale.format('%.0f', x))

In [50]: s
0         1111
1   123.456,78
dtype: float64
```