# format thousands with dots and decimal with commas

Tags: python, pandas

In my work I've been trying to convert some values ​​from the financial market to "more readable values" for people to understand, it always takes some work since I have to keep ordering, merging the values, I often have to keep converting it to a string and then coming back with everything.

I have to put dots whenever thousands and comma to the decimal places, making these two in a simple way already helps a lot.

I need some help with the zeros at the end of the numbers too. Some numbers the pandas or the broker are taking the zeros from the end of the decimal places:

135.40 => 135.4  #wrong way

my dataset:

```
   Ativo Variação Fechamento
  XPIN11   6.34      135.4
  CXRI11   5.56     1593.9
 FAMB11B   4.69     3100.0
 BBFI11B   3.82     2580.0
  FLMA11    3.7        3.92
```

Expected exit:

```
   Ativo Variação Fechamento
  XPIN11   6,34       135,40
  CXRI11   5,56     1.593,90
 FAMB11B   4,69     3.100,00
 BBFI11B   3,82     2.580,00
  FLMA11    3,7         3,92
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why not keep issues of formatting at the very edge of the program?

Comment: use `locale` feature to achieve what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660823/how-can-i-format-a-float-to-separate-by-thousands-inverting-dot-and-commas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I format a float to separate by thousands, inverting dot and commas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660823/how-can-i-format-a-float-to-separate-by-thousands-inverting-dot-and-commas)