# Python Regular Expressions: making multiple different substitutions in a single pass using Groups

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I'm tasked with taking a string, finding all instances of two different types of matches in that string, and performing a similar-but-different replacement on each match of each type, all using a single RegEx and a single pass through `re.sub()`

Specifically I'm looking for any `<` or `<=` and replacing them with `>` and `>=` respectively. Each comparison operator in need of replacement is between two words as defined by `\w*` and zero or more spaces `\s*` on either side.

I have found a regular expression that finds all necessary matches and lumps them into useful groups:

```
((\b\w*(\s*<\s*)\w*\b)|(\b\w*(\s*<=\s*)\w*\b))+
```

This will parse the string such that all comparisons that meet the search criteria are matched, and that all `<` will be in match group `\3` and all `<=` will be in match group `\5`

My question is this: Is there a way to replace all `\3` with `' > '` and all `\5` with `' >= '` in a *single* call to `re.sub()`? I've read through the documentation for the `sub` method in python `re` but haven't been able to find a way, perhaps due to my limited familiarity with the syntax and behavior of the whole system.

I am allowed and expected to compile the regex separately before the substitution and so the final set up will look something like this:

```
r1 = re.compile(r"((\b\w*(\s*<\s*)\w*\b)|(\b\w*(\s*<=\s*)\w*\b))+")
subStr = r" ??? " 

r1.sub( ???, subStr ??? )
```

Here is some example input/output:

input string :

> "v1 < v2 v3 <= v4 v5 > v6 v7 >= v8"

running the substitution would produce:

> "v1 > v2 v3 >= v4 v5 > v6 v7 >= v8"

plugging my pattern and the input string into https://regex101.com/ for python, will show how my pattern matches the input string in the way I described.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python string replace two things at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687018/python-string-replace-two-things-at-once)

Comment: @maxymoo maybe? I'm not allowed to make multiple calls to sub() though so I'm not sure if that solution would be applicable. The answer to this question might be that it's not possible with the RegEx I came up with.

Comment: Your question is unclear since an example input and the expected output are missing. Your pattern looks wrong and doesn't explain what you are trying to do. Add example(s) to your question.

Comment: the second answer only makes a single call to `sub`

Comment: There are no `<=` in your string, write a better example.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I only want to go from `<` to `>` and from `<=` to `>=` not also the other way around.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte i think the question is clear enough, it doesn't need more examples

Comment: Example input edited to be more demonstrative.

Comment: Stupid question (: Why not [replace any `<` with `>`](https://regex101.com/r/uTn135/1) ?

Comment: @bobblebubble because the match specifically has to find the comparison operator as between two words `\w*` and since `=` can't be in a word `\w*` a regular expression wouldn't be able to match `<=` since that would be between a word `\w*` on the left and a single character `=` on the right. I need to find both at once, so I need a match case for `<` and one for `<=` each found between two words.


Unless there's an easier way to do it that I'm not clever enough to find.

If for example, the `>` was at the very start/end of the string, or right before/after another `>' it would be ignored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to make the = optional and to capture parts around the <:

```
re.sub(r'\b(?<=\w)(\s*)<(=?\s*\w)', r'\1>\2', s)
```

for efficiency reasons I started the pattern with the word boundary `\b`, the following lookbehind `(?<=\w)` ensures there's at least one word character.

Comment: This is much simpler and immensely helpful. Just seeing `'\1>\2'` helped me to better understand how the `sub()` method is used.