# How do I perform multiple string replacement with replacement clashes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

I have a list of string replacements. Each replacement is trivial (constant expressions), but the list may contain replacement clashes, like so:

```py
reps = {
    'a': 'b',
    'b': 'c',
    'c': 'a',
}
```

So I expect the string `grab my cat` to become `grbc my abt`.

However, I will not succeed if I perform naive successive replacements like

```py
for pre, post in reps.items():
    string.replace(pre, post)
```

, because of the clashes.. here for instance I'll get `graa my aat` instead.

Is there a standard way to do this in python, while avoiding the boilerplate of taking care of the clashes? Something like `string.multiple_replace(reps)`?
Or do I need to watch the clashes myself?

---

**Note:** I am aware that the above logic contains unresolved questions in the cases where `pre`conditions overlap. `reps` is actually ordered (since python `3.8`) or can be viewed as `[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a')]` to prioritize replacements and solve the ambiguities.

---

**Further note:**
I am also aware that [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8687380/3719101) involving use of temporary buffers like `"%temp%"` is the traditional way to go. However:

- a vanilla implementation of this trick is not robust against attack strings that happen to already contain `"%temp%"`.
- a vanilla implementation of this trick implies performing one or two replacement passes for each elementary replacement in `reps`, which is sad if replacements are numerous or the string is long.

As such, this traditional trick is not enough and the problem needs be tackled with more care.

What I wish to know is whether python offers standard, fast and robust implementation of a solution to this problem.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Possible duplicate indeed. Does it mean I have to solve the clash myself, or does python offer functionality to automate the `%temp%` trick? (*ie.* check that `%temp%` itself does not trigger more clashes, *etc.*)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming single character changes, use `str.translate` (for python 3):

```
>>> str.translate('grab my cat', str.maketrans(reps))
'grbc my abt'
```

Comment: Super useful in the single character case indeed, thanks :)