Substring replacement in data frame, based on a look-up table
As input, I've got a large data frame in R with lists of strings of different lengths, referring to certain codes - like this:
  glt.code glt.phylogeny                   
1 adha1238 adha1238                    
2 adiv1239 adiv1239                    
3 adiw1235 adiw1235                    
4 aerr1238 jikr1238;jikr1238;aerr1238

I would like to replace the codes in the column glt.phylogeny based on their name in this look-up table:
  code     name                       level     
1 adha1238 Adhari                     language
2 adiv1239 Kotia-Adivasi Oriya-Desiya language
3 adiw1235 Adiwasi Garasia            language
4 aerr1238 Aer                        language
5 jikr1238 Jikrio Aer                 dialect 

My desired output looks like this:
  glt.code glt.phylogeny.names                   
1 adha1238 Adhari                    
2 adiv1239 Kotia-Adivasi Oriya-Desiya                    
3 adiw1235 Adiwasi Garasia                    
4 aerr1238 Jikrio Aer;Jikrio Aer;Aer 

I'd like to find a pipelined (dplyr) solution replacing all substrings in a column of a data frame based on a look-up table. I've experimented using str_replace_all and stri_replace_all_fixed, based on other questions on Stack Overflow but without a working result.
The actual data frame and look-up table is much larger than that so a scalable solution would be appreciated.

I think this will get you what you want using str_replace_all by extracting a named vector from your lookup table:
library(tidyverse)
# data
df <- tibble(
  glt.code = c("adha1238", "adiv1239", "adiw1235", "aerr1238"),
  glt.phylogeny = c("adha1238", "adiv1239", "adiw1235", "jikr1238;jikr1238;aerr1238")
)
df_look_up <- tibble(
  code = c("adha1238", "adiv1239", "adiw1235", "aerr1238", "jikr1238"),
  name = c("Adhari", "Kotia-Adivasi Oriya-Desiya", "Adivasi Garasia", "Aer", "Jikrio Aer"),
  level = c("language", 
            "language", "language", "language", "dialect")
)

# create named vector
named_look_up_vector <- df_look_up %>% 
  pull(name, code)

# use str_replace_all
df %>% 
  mutate(glt.phylogeny = str_replace_all(glt.phylogeny, named_look_up_vector))
# # A tibble: 4 × 2
#   glt.code glt.phylogeny             
#   <chr>    <chr>                     
# 1 adha1238 Adhari                    
# 2 adiv1239 Kotia-Adivasi Oriya-Desiya
# 3 adiw1235 Adivasi Garasia           
# 4 aerr1238 Jikrio Aer;Jikrio Aer;Aer 


Accepted because this seems to be the most concise and general solution. It's slower than the join-based solution below but doesn't require a fixed delimiter between the substrings.

Worth keeping in mind this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77198098/how-to-perform-multiple-string-pattern-replacement-without-overwriting-previous

Using purrr::map on the strsplit codes, then match the name with code
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  summarize(glt.phylogeny.names = purrr::map(strsplit(glt.phylogeny, ";"), ~ 
    paste0(loup$name[match(.x, loup$code)], collapse=";")), .by = glt.code)

output
  glt.code        glt.phylogeny.names
1 adha1238                     Adhari
2 adiv1239 Kotia-Adivasi Oriya-Desiya
3 adiw1235            Adiwasi Garasia
4 aerr1238  Jikrio Aer;Jikrio Aer;Aer

If performance is an issue, try data.table. An equivalent approach can be
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, .(glt.phylogeny.names = sapply(strsplit(glt.phylogeny, ";"), \(x) 
  paste0(loup$name[match(x, loup$code)], collapse=";"))), by = glt.code]
   glt.code        glt.phylogeny.names
     <char>                     <char>
1: adha1238                     Adhari
2: adiv1239 Kotia-Adivasi Oriya-Desiya
3: adiw1235            Adiwasi Garasia
4: aerr1238  Jikrio Aer;Jikrio Aer;Aer

Data
df <- structure(list(glt.code = c("adha1238", "adiv1239", "adiw1235",
"aerr1238"), glt.phylogeny = c("adha1238", "adiv1239", "adiw1235",
"jikr1238;jikr1238;aerr1238")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",
"2", "3", "4"))

loup <- structure(list(code = c("adha1238", "adiv1239", "adiw1235",
 "aerr1238", "jikr1238"), name = c("Adhari", "Kotia-Adivasi Oriya-Desiya",
"Adiwasi Garasia", "Aer", "Jikrio Aer"), level = c("language",
"language", "language", "language", "dialect")), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))


Split the data on semi-colon, join it with lookup table and collapse the names into semi-colon separated string.
Assuming the dataframe are called df1 and df2 you can do :
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  separate_longer_delim(glt.phylogeny, ";") %>%
  left_join(df2, join_by(glt.phylogeny == code)) %>%
  summarise(name = paste0(name, collapse = ";"), .by = glt.code)

#  glt.code                       name
#1 adha1238                     Adhari
#2 adiv1239 Kotia-Adivasi Oriya-Desiya
#3 adiw1235            Adiwasi Garasia
#4 aerr1238  Jikrio Aer;Jikrio Aer;Aer

data
df1 <- structure(list(glt.code = c("adha1238", "adiv1239", "adiw1235", 
"aerr1238"), glt.phylogeny = c("adha1238", "adiv1239", "adiw1235", 
"jikr1238;jikr1238;aerr1238")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(code = c("adha1238", "adiv1239", "adiw1235", "aerr1238", 
"jikr1238"), name = c("Adhari", "Kotia-Adivasi Oriya-Desiya", 
"Adiwasi Garasia", "Aer", "Jikrio Aer"), level = c("language", 
"language", "language", "language", "dialect")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))


This solution is also very concise and faster than the answer using string replacement. If there is a fixed delimiter between substrings (";" in my example), this seems to be the best solution.

Is this what you are looking for?.
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df1 <- tibble(
  glt.code = c("adha1238", "adiv1239", "adiw1235", "aerr1238"),
  glt.phylogeny = c("adha1238", "adiv1239", "adiw1235", "jikr1238;jikr1238;aerr1238")
)

df2 <- tibble(
  code = c("adha1238", "adiv1239", "adiw1235", "aerr1238", "jikr1238"),
  name = c("Adhari", "Kotia-Adivasi Oriya-Desiya", "Adivasi Garasia", "Aer", "Jikrio Aer")
)

# Function to replace codes with names
replace_codes_with_names <- function(codes, lookup_table) {
  codes_list <- str_split(codes, ";")[[1]]
  names_list <- lookup_table$name[match(codes_list, lookup_table$code)]
  paste(names_list, collapse = ";")
}

# desired output
desired_output <- df1 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(glt.phylogeny.names = replace_codes_with_names(glt.phylogeny, df2)) %>%
ungroup()


