# I've tried to create a cipher but it changes the same letter twice

Tags: python

I've got a project for school where I'm supposed to create a cipher where it changes the letters to make a word but when I run it it changes the letter but changes it again as it goes through (like when I put in oTr it's supposed to put out "sea" but instead outputs "oea"). The project is already late so please help. This is what I have at the moment:

```
decode_length = int(input("Enter a string length to decode: "))
letters = str.lower(input("Enter a string with " + str(decode_length) + " characters: "))

counter = 0

while decode_length > counter:
    letters = letters.replace("a", "r")
    letters = letters.replace("e", "t")
    letters = letters.replace("o", "s")
    letters = letters.replace("s", "o")
    letters = letters.replace("t", "e")
    letters = letters.replace("r", "a")
    counter = counter + 1
print(letters)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace two things at once in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687018/how-to-replace-two-things-at-once-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
decode_length = int(input("Enter a string length to decode: "))
letters = str.lower(input("Enter a string with " + str(decode_length) + " characters: "))
replace_dict = {"a":"r",
                "e":"t",
                "o":"s",
                "s":"o",
                "t":"e",
                "r":"a"}
for character in letters:
    letters = letters.replace(character, replace_dict[character])

print(letters)
```